# draggable events for an extjs panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, panel, draggable, extjs4.1

Is there a listener for an end-of-drag event when I make a given panel "draggable"? I've found I can make a panel draggable around inside another panel by enabling the "draggable" attribute in its initial config, but I'd like to capture the events when the drag is happening. Looking at the docs, I see I can add listeners like "load", but I don't see a list of all the supported events I can listen for. Can this be handled in the configuration or should I use an addListener()? Either way, what's the syntax and how can I figure this out using the docs? I'd just like to be able to fire a function every time my draggable panel is moved around its container. Thanks.

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
     draggable: true,
     width: 200,
     height: 200,
});
```

I was hoping I could do something like this...

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    draggable: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    listeners: {            
       dragging: function(e) { 
           // being dragged
       },
       dropped: function(e) { 
           // dropped
       },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't do this with listerens in this case. There are four template methods that you can override

- **[onBeforeStart](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.ComponentDragger-method-onBeforeStart)**
- **[onDrag](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.ComponentDragger-method-onDrag)**
- **[onEnd](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.ComponentDragger-method-onEnd)**
- **[onStart](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.ComponentDragger-method-onStart)**

So you can do it like:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
     draggable: {
         onDrag: function(e) {
              // do what you like
         },
         onEnd: function(e) {
              // do what you like
         }
     },
     width: 200,
     height: 200,
});
```

Note the argument **[e](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventObject)** is the event-Object

Comment: @Leprosy No you are wrong. These are template methods, meaning that they are meant to get overridden.

Comment: Just tried in 4.1.0 with a Window. Drag normal behavior didn't work after the method override.

But when the Window is draggable, it does use ComponentDragger which has a dragstart event that fires on the window that you can listen for.

Comment: @Leprosy A Window is a special subtype of a panel, it uses a custom component dragger which itself set the template method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to modify components on a `Ext.window.Window` just before the drag starts, and found in the sencha forums that a `draggable` window listens to the `dragstart` event, perhaps it works with a `Panel` too.

I used this code:

```
listeners: {
    dragstart: function() {
        console.log('we are starting the drag');
    }
}
```

And worked like a charm. Works here in my app, using Ext JS 4.1.0

For the end of drag, I've found that the `move` event of the `Ext.window.Window` suits the need.

Answer (score 1):

For use dragstart listener with Ext.panel.Panel, you need to set simpleDrag: true.

But when simpleDrag is active, you can't drop, just drag/move the Panel as a Window.